# Why doesn't the compiler complain when I try to access a non-existent array value?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

My C++ book says that if I have

```
int anArray[25];
```

and I try to evaluate

```
anArray[25] = 0;
```

the program will simply overwrite whatever value is stored in the next memory address past the end of the array. Why?

My thinking is compilers are stupid in that regard. All the compiler cares to do is calculate where anArray[25] *should* be and then move on.

Comment: C++ favors performance over safety.  It expects you to already know what you are doing well enough to avoid accesses beyond the end of the array.

Comment: I don't know Robert.  In this precise example, if the lines were right after each other, or, more reasonably, `anArray` was `const`, the compiler should be able to figure this out, shouldn't it?.

Comment: Sure, if that was the goal of a C++ compiler.  It isn't.  Its goal is to hand you the saw with no safety guards and expects you to use it in a way that doesn't cut your hand off.

Comment: The compiler may be able to figure it out and issue a warning or a compilation error. The standard simply doesn't *require* it to do so. The book's explanation that “the program will simply overwrite whatever is stored in the next memory address past the end of the array” is a likely but by no means the required outcome. See [the great answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/) for a more detailed discussion. It may also instrument your code to catch the error at run-time, which is what sanitizers do. The C++ standard is flexible enough to permit all of this.

Comment: *Compilers* aren't stupid in that regard; *the C++ language* (and the C language on which it's based) is stupid in that regard.  This is a well-known problem called "buffer overflow* and it's been a major source of online security holes for literally over a quarter of a century, but a lot of programmers are stupid in that regard, and have failed to abandon C in favor of a less stupidly-insecure language.

Comment: C++ doesn't check array bounds for the same reason that [this car](http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/MMFR_PlymouthRock-876x534.jpg) doesn't have seat belts.

Comment: What exact compiler are you using? Did you enable *all* warnings?

Comment: For additional reference - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398703/why-does-c-have-undefined-behaviour-and-other-languages-like-c-or-java-don

Answer (score 7):

Why doesn't the compiler complain? Because it's not required to. The language standard describes the circumstances that require a compiler to complain, and a mere array-index-out-of-bounds is not one of them.

Decent static analysis tools are capable of detecting this scenario for specific cases. The simple case of:

```
int anArray[25];
anArray[25] = 0;
```

will likely be detected by most static analysis tools. But C and C++ compilers are not required to do so.

As for why the standard doesn't require them to... why should it?

Your particular scenario is only trivially detectable for two reasons:

1. The compiler has knowledge of the size of that array.
2. The index you are using is known by the compiler at compile time.

In real-world cases of index-out-of-bounds scenarios, one or both of these will usually not be true. And no, [C++ does not in fact have ways of knowing what the length of an array is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array). Because you can do this:

```
int *arr = new int[25];
int *arr2 = arr + 5;
```

`arr2` is just as much of an array as `arr`. And yet, there is no way to determine how many elements are in `arr2`.

And even if you could... that wouldn't be something you would know at *compile time*. Accessing said length would be a runtime memory access. Once the array becomes an `int*`, it's no longer an array; it's just a pointer, which you can access as though it were an array. The compiler no longer has certain knowledge of what gets stored there. So you've lost #1.

So there is no way that the *compiler* could complain in most of the real-world cases that are problematic.

The next, unasked, question is why doesn't the compiler emit runtime code to verify things like this? Because such runtime safety takes time, and by default C and C++ are *not safe languages*. By design, they are intended to achieve the fastest possible performance, even if that means that writing broken (or breakable) code is easier than writing correct code.

You can like it or hate it, applaud it or deride it. However you feel about it, that's the design ethic of the language(s).

Comment: There is nothing in the C++ standard, however, that says that a compiler *must not* emit run-time bounds checking code. And there are compilers that provide options to do that, actually.

Comment: @5gon12eder: I'd be curious to see how you could do runtime bounds checking on a pointer parameter variable which may or may not point to an array. At least, not without breaking ABI compatibility, since most ABIs don't pass an integer size along with pointers. Or, as in the example I provided, where you get a pointer to part of an array. I'm sure there are compilers that can emit code to do *some* bounds checking. But it would never be *comprehensive*.

Comment: I'm thinking about the tricks that sanitizers do. Augmenting pointers to know what they point to would be another option. Sure, it would be ABI breaking, but the C++ standard has nothing to say about ABIs as far as I'm aware. I'm not *encouraging* compilers should do this. Just wanted to mention that reliably aborting the program with an error message would be a perfectly valid response to invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

MIT (I think) has some great online courses archived that I've been observing.  One of the really cool and powerful things about being able to do this is that you can specifically access memory that you wouldn't normally be allowed to.  This offers you all sorts of ways to do things you probably shouldn't. ;)

But I think the main reason that this is possible is that **an array variable** really **only stores the address of the first index**.  It does not have a way, that I know of, to also store specifically how large the array is.  Obviously, somewhere in memory this information existed at some point because an appropriate amount of memory was set aside for the array of a certain size, but for whatever reason this is not easily retrievable.

Comment: That's only true for pointers to arrays, or for arrays in C.  C++ actually does have a notion of array size; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

Comment: This is not "cool and powerful"; it's a massive security hole masquerading as a language feature for 1337 haxx0rz.

Comment: @MasonWheeler But what I'm seeing as being really neat and powerful about it is that you can pass this address pointer to a function which accepts it as a char[] address.  You can then parse it out into whatever data type it really is.  Whether it's an int[], long int[], or whatever.  Send it off as a char[] and search through the memory at your leisure.

Comment: @WaymanBellIII There are plenty of ways to do that without opening up massive security holes.  Civilized languages generally do what you're describing with *streams*.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I'd rather not have this discussion go off into a flame war about programming languages. What can be said, though, is that reading data out of random pointers – even if it might *appear* to work – is undefined behavior in C and C++. If a program relies on this for its proper functioning, it is broken by the standard.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: In cases where a programmer knows about memory layout and a compiler allows the programmer to exploit such knowledge, it can be a powerful feature.  What's dangerous is having a compiler decide that certain checks like comparing a pointer to the start and end of a memory block can be omitted because in all cases where the Standard imposes any requirements the pointers would need to be in bounds.  The authors of the Standard didn't think it necessary to define behavior in such cases when using hardware which could handle such operations usefully because...

Comment: ...they thought people designing implementations would use reasonable judgment in such cases.  If an implementation is going to claim to be suitable for systems programming, it should support features necessary to such purposes, whether or not the Standard requires them.  An implementation which targets common hardware which supports such features, but doesn't expose such support to the programmer, should be viewed as suitable only for specialized purposes which only involve data from trustworthy sources.